# Error generating pods project - Pod install

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have a working project that uses cocoa pods. I tried to 'pod install' and got this weird error:

```
Generating Pods project
  - Creating Pods project
  - Adding source files to Pods project
  - Adding frameworks to Pods project
  - Adding libraries to Pods project
  - Adding resources to Pods project
  - Linking headers
  - Installing targets
    - Installing target `Pods-NIDropDown` iOS 7.0
    - Installing target `Pods-SDWebImage` iOS 7.0
    - Installing target `Pods-SQCommonUtils` iOS 7.0
    - Installing target `Pods` iOS 7.0
  - Running post install hooks
  - Writing Xcode project file to `Pods/Pods.xcodeproj`
2015-06-27 01:20:37.359 ruby[3841:138874] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-8123.33/IDEFoundation/Initialization/IDEInitialization.m:590
Details:  Assertion failed: _initializationCompletedSuccessfully
Function: BOOL IDEIsInitializedForUserInteraction()
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fedd50822b0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x00000001057f7047 -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInFunction:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1  0x00000001057f67d4 _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x00000001057f6a40 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x00000001057f69a2 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  4  0x0000000106bbf1a9 IDEIsInitializedForUserInteraction (in IDEFoundation)
  5  0x000000010ab2ea5d +[PBXProject projectWithFile:errorHandler:readOnly:] (in DevToolsCore)
  6  0x000000010ab305e2 +[PBXProject projectWithFile:errorHandler:] (in DevToolsCore)
  7  0x00007fff9262af44 ffi_call_unix64 (in libffi.dylib)
Abort trap: 6
```

No idea why i got a error Writing Xcode project file to `Pods/Pods.xcodeproj`. I've tried reinstall cocoa pods, but not succeed.

I'm kind of noob with iOS development, so any tips would be nice.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was having this problem working with Xcode 7 beta 2. Setting xcode-select back to the released version of Xcode helped me.

Try running this in terminal:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Then try your CocoaPods install again:

```
pod install
```

I then had no problems going back to the Xcode beta with this command:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
```

Comment: Glad I could help, @Thiago Galvão Franco. Would you be so kind as to mark my answer as accepted?

Comment: This was extremely helpful, @AaronSurrain! I would upvote this answer ten times if I could...

Comment: Thanks a lot saved my day

Answer (score 28):

Seems to be an issue with project serialization with Xcode 7. Cocoapods relies on xcodeproj, which has a bug with the latest betas. They've put out a quick release to address the issue. Run this in the terminal:

`gem install xcodeproj -v 0.24.3`

(may have to sudo that)

Comment: Current version at time of writing is 0.28.2, so suggest doing a `sudo gem update` instead.

Answer (score 21):

For those getting the error after the recent Xcode update, I did the above and it didn't work until I updated cocoa pods (from version 0.36.0) :

```
sudo gem update
```

This updated it to 0.38.2 (I have also seen references to 0.37.x having problems)

Comment: you da real MVP :D

Answer (score 4):

You just follow the below terminal commands. It may help you.

```
$sudo gem update —system
$sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
$sudo gem install cocoapods
$pod setup
$cd <project path>
$pod init
add files(frameworks)($pod outdated- if already pod exists)
$pod install
$pod update(if you need)
```

Answer (score 3):

Before retrying the 'pod install' open a second terminal window and tail your system log:

```
tail -f /var/log/system.log
```

You might be surprised what you learn.  Mine reported that

> pod install[20810]: [MT] DVTPlugInLoading: Failed to load code for plug-in com.apple.dt.dbg.DebuggerFoundation (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerFoundation.ideplugin), error = Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3587 "The bundle “DebuggerFoundation” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources." (dlopen_preflight(/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/DebuggerFoundation.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/DebuggerFoundation): Library not loaded: @rpath/IBAutolayoutFoundation.framework/Versions/A/IBAutolayoutFoundation

So since my installation of Xcode 7.0.1 via the Mac App Store ended up being corrupted none of the suggestions by all the other helpful responders here were destined to work.

These things never crop up when you have plenty of time to throughly troubleshoot them.  It certainly isn't that time for our release schedule right now, so what worked here (OS X 10.10.5, departing Xcode 6.4 for Xcode 7.0.1) was (and this is after having asked the App Store to reinstall 7.0.1)

```
rm -Rf /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Followed by asking the Mac App Store to reinstall Xcode 7.0.1

Then we were able to proceed with updating CocoaPods, etc. etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo xcode-select -r` fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

Everyone suggested an xcode problem, what solved it for me was removing all of cocoapods gems, then reinstalling them:

```
gem list | grep cocoapods | xargs gem uninstall -aIx
gem uninstall xcodeproj
```